# Facebook Login Using Fragments Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-login

I am trying to set up facebook login for android. I have follow all the documentation online to get this going, my main reference has been [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/).

I have no "errors" in my code yet nothing appears, and I do have a feeling nothing would actually happen if something appeared. Let me show you to better understand:

**ManageFacebookFragment**

```
public class ManageFacebookFragment extends Fragment {
    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;

private static final String TAG = MainScreenFragmentPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private final List<String> permissions;


public ManageFacebookFragment() {
    permissions = Arrays.asList("user_status");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /** Getting the arguments to the Bundle object */
    final Bundle data = getArguments();

    /** Getting integer data of the key current_page from the bundle */
    mCurrentPosition = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_accounts_facebook, container,
            false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    // authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private final Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

}
```

**settings_accounts_facebook.xml**

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />
```

Essentially all I have is button that I want to be able to press to get the user to authenticate with facebook... right now when I run the app it is just simply a blank screen... I wonder if this has to do with the fragment implementation of facebook login, not sure. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - forgot to add each sub fragment to the pager - it was going to a default blank entry.